# How do we disable GET option endpoint for /oauth/token and only keep POST option in spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my spring boot project, I'm using spring 'spring-cloud-starter-oauth2' dependency to enable oauth security using JWT tokens. The dependency exposes two endpoints for /oauth/token with GET and POST options. How do I disable GET endpoint and only keep POST option?
My swagger UI and shows both GET and POST endpoints and that's how I noticed it.

Comment: What is your problem with the 'GET' endpoint? Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: It a requirement my company asked for. They just want the POST endpoint for /oauth/token. I tried fiddling with AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer but it doesn't expose any functionality to disable an endpoint.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. You would write your own OAuth2 implementation (for example fork Spring Security OAuth2 project on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly allow only POST method on the `/oauth/token` endpoint with the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
  }

}
```